# Qt equivalent of boost::shared_from_this?

Tags: qt, boost

I have some classes that derive from boost::shared_from_this - how can I perform the equivalent in Qt? (without reimplementing a similar shared_from_this; I'd prefer a no-inheritance solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QEnableSharedFromThis` was recently added to Qt and will be in the 5.4 release.

- Patch: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/60346/
- Documentation: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qenablesharedfromthis.html

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the ability to get `QSharedPointer` from `this` - there was such a [feature request](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-7287), but as far as I can see it's still not implemented in the official Qt release.